# Odoo ERP how to save lines when I press "Save & Close" button from Pop Up window?

Tags: python, odoo

One of the most annoying feature of Open ERP is:
I have to press main **Save** *button(picture 2, item 3)* on left top corner even though I already pressed **Save and Close** *picture 1, item 1* from Pop Up window of products.
I included screenshot from Warehouse module as example. Please assume 'stock.picking' is already created, so it wouldn't cause integrity problem.

> I feel last step is redundant.
>   Is it possible to save products lines without having to press **Save** button *picture 2, item 3*?
>   Is it possible to override **Save & Close button**?
>   Is it possible to call **Save** button when I press **Save & Close button**?

[image: Save and Close button]
[image: Main Save button]

Comment: In that case the stock move lines are related with the stock picking. So first you have to create (save) the stock picking in the database. Do you want to create the stock moves an after that you want to create the relation with stock picking? I think that would give you some integrity issues

Comment: I edited my question. Please assume stock.picking is already created when you start inserting products.

Comment: That's just not the way Odoo works. You could write a Wizard/Pop-Up to create `stock.move`s without editing the picking, but then you have to handle the relations within the Wizard/Pop-up and should reload the picking in background after closing the Wizard/Pop-Up.

Comment: IMO...this behaviour is an advantage because it saves you the hassles of switching pages just to create "child" objects of the parent object, instead you can just do it from one single page....the only thing i can think of is to override the create method of `stock picking` and call the create method of `stock.move`...but then you would still need a way to refresh the page to tell the user that the record has been saved

Answer (score 0):

You can't save One2many record without saving parent form.
As child(one2many) is dependent on Parent Form Class. and making any shortcut for saving one2many record without saving parent can affect system badly.

So Please follow the standard process.